# How to read JSON array values in Spring controller

Tags: java, json, spring

I would like to iterate Products and get the list of name,code and price and set in my Model class. Any help would be really appreciated - how can I iterate this. When I use obj.get("Products") - it just printing as string - got stuck to iterate.

```
{
    "id": "skd3303ll333",
    "Products": [{
            "name": "apple",
            "code": "iphone-393",
            "price": "1939"

        },
        {
            "name": "ipad",
            "code": "ipad-3939",
            "price": "900"

        }
    ]
}


@PostMapping(path="/create", consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> create(@RequestBody  Map<String, Object> obj ) { 
System.out.println("Products :" + obj.get("Products"));
  }
```

Comment: why don't you map this response directly into model using jackson

Comment: How to do that? Sorry I'm new to Spring and Java - if its very basic question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this,

1) By type casting (personally i will not prefer this)

```
List<Map<Object,Object>> productslist = (List<Map<Object, Object>>) obj.get("products");
    for(Map entry: productslist) {
        for(Object s: entry.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(s.toString());
            System.out.println(entry.get(s).toString());

        }
    }
```

2) Mapping directly to Model class, for this approach you need Jackson library in buildpath

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(unknown =true)
public class Customer {

@JsonProperty("id")
private String id;
@JsonProperty("products")
private List<Products> products;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public List<Products> getProducts() {
    return products;
}

public void setProducts(List<Products> products) {
    this.products = products;
   }

}
 @JsonIgnoreProperties(unknown =true)
 class Products{
@JsonProperty("name")
private String name;
@JsonProperty("code")
private String code;
@JsonProperty("price")
private String price;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
   }

}
```

**Controller**

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> create(@RequestBody  Customer obj ) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You need POJO structure with two classes:

```
public class Product {
    private String name;
    private String code;
    private int price;
}

public class ProductsGroup {
    private long id;
    private List<Product> products;
    // getters/setters
}
```

And change your method signature to:

```
@PostMapping(path="/create", consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ProductsGroup> create(@RequestBody ProductsGroup productGroup) 
{ 
   System.out.println("Products :" + productGroup.getProducts());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to process the json using a `Map<String, Object> obj`, which could be possible in some way, but mostly what you want to do is define a single or multiple POJO classes. These represent the json.

```
public class IdWrapper {
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty("Products")
    private List<Product> products;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
}

public class Product {
    private String name;
    private String code;
    private String price;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

And in you controller like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("test")
public class DemoController {
    @PostMapping()
    public void test(@RequestBody IdWrapper productsWrapper) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```